# Is it possible to write on a image file(Any other file) inside a .war?

Tags: java, tomcat, openshift, java-ee-7

I have a war containing image file(Any file) created and deployed in OpenShift on Tomcat 7 Server. I'm able to read the files present inside the war but I'm unable to create new or modify the existing.

On research, it is said that Writing files into a WAR – Another BAD IDEA.

Please suggest..

Thanks

Comment: Yes, bad idea. You are not supposed to change the war file. The idea of these deployment artifacts are that you know exactly what is in there (so that you can deploy the same software again, or make very specific code updates). Especially important for cloud deployments. Application state/data should go somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use external resource host**

According to your request you should use an another external resource provider services to host images or another resource files. You can use an external `ftp` server to perform your requirement. Then you can link them to your webpage using it's web link.